# How to fix Facebook Circular Redirect?

Tags: facebook, redirect

I have a page that redirects to another page
I'm trying to test my url on:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

I get this error:

```
Errors That Must Be Fixed:
Circular Redirect:‎ Circular redirect path detected (see Redirect Path section for details).

Warnings That Should Be Fixed:
‎The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other
tags.‎
```

1. How can I fix this problem?
2. How to detect Facebook and, if it is Facebook, don't redirect?

Comment: I have some questions too. What are you using to redirect your page? What scripting language we are talking about?

Comment: i use Response.Redirect() in asp

Answer (score 67):

I just resolved this by adding a "/" to the end of the Facebook URL meta tag. So, changed

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/path"/>
```

to

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/path/"/>
```

and that did the trick!

Comment: Still works in 2017! My problem was actually a missing `?` to start the query, but it got me looking in the right place.

Answer (score 7):

It should be clear from the details given below in the redirect path section of the debugger output:
In most cases this happens because you've specified an `og:url` tag pointing to (for example) `example.com/articles` and this redirects to `example.com/articles/` - the crawler then goes to `example.com/articles` and gets the og:url tag pointing it back to `example.com/articles`

Answer (score 5):

I've found a workaround and although it's on a `LAMP` stack something similar must be possible with `.NET`.

Checking the `Apache server` log while using the `Facebook Linter` I got:

> 69.63.189.246 - - [09/Jan/2012:03:54:45 +0000] "GET /test1.php HTTP/1.1" 200 8879 "-" >  "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

I now check if the User-Agent contains: `facebookexternalhit` if so I display the original page, if not I redirect to the new url.

You can use the following `RewriteCond` in `Apache` to make sure that your rewrite rule will only run if the User-Agent **IS NOT** (pay attention to the exclamation mark) `facebookexternalhit`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !facebookexternalhit
```

This solution is risky, if Facebook decides to change their User-Agent header you will be royally ... but for now it seems to do the trick.

Comment: This is rather hacky, but it was the only thing that could fix the circular redirect problem at the same time that kept all my Facebook likes intact.

Answer (score 4):

Check the `Canonical URL` in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug as to where it's getting redirected. If there is a 302 redirect, then either you have to remove that redirect or give the redirected path as `og:URL` meta tag value.

If `http` is getting redirect to `https`. Then give `https://example.com` as the new value of og:URL.

Please note this will reset your all old comments.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe adding the title after the page load helps

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    var meta = document.createElement('meta');
    meta.setAttribute("property", "og:url");
    meta.setAttribute("content", location.href);
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(meta);    
// ]]>
</script>
```

http://digdog.tumblr.com/post/1134982957/integrate-tumblr-template-with-facebook-open-graph

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was **canonical url** was on `http` and fetched url was on `https` switching it to https the it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had same error:
In my case the problem was www. in canonical url against fetched.
Matched and problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Hard to notice at first but Heroku was redirecting me from `domain.heroku.com` to `domain.herokuapp.com`.

Strangely, the cause of the problem was
`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => mydomain.herokuapp.com }` even though no mailer is involved.