# Wordpress preview issue with facebook

Tags: css, facebook, wordpress, preview

I just want to start of by saying that I'm a complete noob when it comes to programing, and don't have a lot of experience with HTML or CSS.  I know this place is a bit more advanced and geared mainly for programmers and developers, but the only reason I come here is because I couldn't find an answer in any of the other forums.  I don't know if I can solve my problem by editing the CSS file in wordpress, but I'm hoping that some of you can chime in and let me know.  The problem I have in a nutshell is that when I post a link of my blog to facebook, facebook doesn't generate the correct data or show any image preview.  Here's the post I submitted at the wordpress forum:

> > I just got a new website, and setup a new wordpress blog on their server. It took a while, but everything is up and running for the most part. I am however, having a really hard time getting any of my post preview to show up when linking to facebook. My website is http://www.limonphotography.com/blog. When I run the same link through facebook's debugger, I get the following error sometimes:
> >
> > Could Not Follow Redirect Path: Using data from .http://www.limonphotography.com/blog/ because there was an error following the redirect path.
> >        Circular Redirect Path: Circular redirect path detected (see 'Redirect Path' section for details).
> >        Could Not Follow Redirect: URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed.
> >
> > My wordpress URL is :http://limonphotography.com/blog but I made the site URL pointing to :http://www.limonphotography.com/blog since it's easier. Original blog is hosted with the site I have my hosting with, so the original WordPress is at http://mukul12031.c4.cmdwebsites.com/blog. Can anyone tell me why I am getting these errors, or why the preview is not showing up?

Again, I apologize if this is too simple of a questions, but I just can't figure it out on my own.  If anyone can help me, I would be very grateful.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does your og:url meta tag look like? Please include all relevant code, including all of the meta tags you - or your client - are using.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to try appending a trailing slash to your og:url tag (example: "http://mysite.com/"). Sounds stupid, I know, [but it's worked for some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229656/how-to-fix-facebook-circular-redirect#9901553)

Another thread on this issue has yielded the following information, courtesy of Lizzbizz on [this Wordpress Support thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-find-the-cause-of-circular-redirect-path-error-and-fb-sharing-problem):

> "From what I can tell, this turned out to be a problem with GoDaddy
>   hosting services. They were applying a 302 Redirect Filter to the
>   server that was hosting my domain and it caused the problems. After I
>   emailed them a few times they finally fixed it. Try googling "GoDaddy
>   302 Redirect Problem" and you will see lots of other posts!
>
> If you are not getting the 302 problem, but just have trouble getting
>   the image or description to appear when you share a link on Facebook,
>   you can use one of the WP plugins for Open Graph data like [Simple
>   Facebook Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/) or [Facebook Open Graph Meta](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-open-graph-meta/) in WordPress and that
>   should fix it!"

Comment: Thank you Mario for your response.  I changed my url settings to http://limonphotography.com/blog, but it still did not fix the issue.  I think it might be  the 302 redirect problem as you mentioned since I am using godaddy.  I'll contact them today and see.  It's strange though.  I had an older site through them using bludomain as a host, and this problem was not there before.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to say. Let me know if they come back to you with any helpful information.